# InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable

Tags: javascript, firefox, html5-video

The following works in Chrome but not Firefox:

```js
var myVideo = document.getElementById('myVideo')
myVideo.currentTime = 570
```

```html
<video id="myVideo" controls>
<source src="myVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

In Firefox it says

> InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not,
>   or is no longer, usable

for line 2.

Comment: This is caused by [Firefox Bug #1188887](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1188887) and is already fixed in Firefox beta, I believe. Currently your best bet is to use a solution like the one proposed by adeneo or to catch the exception and retry after a while.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That error occurs when the object, in this case the video, hasn't loaded enough to be able to set the `currentTime` and skip forward.

You'd have to wait until the video can be played before you can set the `currentTime`

```
var myVideo = document.getElementById('myVideo')

myVideo.addEventListener('canplaythrough', function() {
    myVideo.currentTime = 570;
}, false);
```