# Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable

Tags: javascript, video

I'm using `seekToNextFrame` which is an experimental mozilla thing: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/seekToNextFrame

I'm using this to go over all the frames, sometimes, near the last frames of the video I get an error:

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable

```js
const video_src = "600_frames_in_120fps.mp4";


let canvas,
    ctx,
    video;


async function process_frame(e) {

    const video = e.target;

    const bitmap = await createImageBitmap(video);
    ctx.drawImage(bitmap, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    if (!video.ended) {
        video.seekToNextFrame();        
    }
}



async function init() {

    if (!HTMLMediaElement.prototype.seekToNextFrame) {
        // TODO display error in body
        console.log(
            `[ERROR] HTMLMediaElement seekToNextFrame not supported;
            are you using firefox?`);
        return;
    }

    canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    document.body.append(canvas);
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    video = document.createElement('video');
    video.src = video_src;
    video.volume = 0; // required for play() to work
    document.body.append(video);

    video.addEventListener("seeked", process_frame);

    await video.play();

    video.currentTime = 0; // trigger seeked
}

init();
```

console.log did not gave any `undefined`.

For me it smells like a bug similar to:

[InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34970272/invalidstateerror-an-attempt-was-made-to-use-an-object-that-is-not-or-is-no-lo)

But I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The error "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable" suggests that the video is no longer accessible. This could be because the video ended or is stopped.

You have checked if the video is over using the ended property of the video before calling the seekToNextFrame() method with the following code.

```
if (!video.ended) {
    video.seekToNextFrame();        
}
```

But you also have to check if the video is paused. Modify your code to this.

```
if (!video.ended && !video.paused) {
    video.seekToNextFrame();        
}
```

This way, you can avoid the exception from being thrown when the video has reached the end or if the video has been paused or stopped.

The code can be further improved. But the above modification can fix the problem.

Hope this helps. If not comment or edit the question and I'll try to solve it.